# Use String.split() remove a custom defined sub-string

Tags: java, string, split

I need to split string based on a custom defined sub-string `$ This is a Comments $` `$ ThisISalsoAComments $`

So the string

`Question 1 $ MultipleChoice $ Question 2 $ One Choice $ Question 3 $ $$$$ $`

Will get the following string after split

```
["Question", "1", "Question", "2", "Question", "3"]
```

`$<Space>anyStringhere<Space>$` is a comment, this is in fat removing all the comments from the string by split

Comment: The result is a single string value or is it an array of strings.  I only ask because your format is printed like a printed string array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following regex will do it:

```java
String regex = " (?:\\$ .*? \\$(?: |$))?";

String input = "Question 1 $ MultipleChoice $ Question 2 $ One Choice $ Question 3 $ $$$$ $";
String[] result = input.split(regex);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

*Output*

```
[Question, 1, Question, 2, Question, 3]
```

Depending on the details of your requirements, you might want to replace the spaces in the regex with `\\s` or `\\s+`.

*Explanation*

```
" "         Match a space (word separator, or beginning of comment)
"(?:"       Start of optional non-capturing group:
  "\\$ "      Match '$ ' (start-of-comment marker)
  ".*?"       Match anything reluctantly, i.e. match the comment content
  " \\$"      Match ' $' (end-of-comment marker)
  "(?: |$)"   Match a space after the trailing '$', or match end of input
")?"        End of optional non-capturing group
```

Comment: This simpler regex also works: `" (\\$ [^$]+ \\$ )?"` and protects against malformed tokens

Comment: @Bohemian That doesn't work, since it won't remove the last comment: `[Question, 1, Question, 2, Question, 3, $, $$$$, $]`

Comment: Yes just re-reading the Q now and I didn’t see that edge case all the way off the page

Comment: @Bohemian That edge case is why I used `".*?"` and "(?: |$)", and I always use non-capturing groups if I don't need the content captured, since capturing would be a waste.

Comment: But this would work `" (\\$ .*? \\$ ?)?"` no? I never use non capturing groups because I favour readability over nano-second sized performance improvements, unless I need the NCG to keep group numbers sane

Comment: @Bohemian Depends, does input `"foo $ bar $baz"` have a comment? From the example in the question, I inferred that the `$` signs must be surrounded by spaces to be treated as comment markers, so my regex says there's no comment in that input.

Comment: I see. I think you are right

Comment: @Bohemian Yeah, it's all about edge case rules, which of course are almost always missing when people write requirements. Always a hurdle when you have to get back to the customer to clarify how they want the edge cases handled, especially when they then just say "we'll figure that out when it happens", and you then have to explain to them that we need to code the rules now, not later.